# Data retrieval from dropdown list to the textbox in same page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using asp.net with c#, I have a drop down list which has a list of `varchar` items and I have a text box, the moment I select an item in the drop down list it should display in the textbox. I have tried the code so far, but it is showing a `Null Reference Exception`.

```
Patient ID:<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="PatientID" 
    DataValueField="PatientID">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConStr %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [PatientID] FROM [Patient_Data] WHERE ([DummyValue] = @DummyValue)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="Y" Name="DummyValue" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

 Hospital No.:
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="HospNo" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
```

In C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string pid = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        HospNo.Text = pid.ToString();//Error in this line

        //other code
    }
 }
```

Is there any other method? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your drop down list add one more attribute **AutoPostback** and set it to true as shown below :

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="PatientID" 
    DataValueField="PatientID" AutoPostback="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

And your code has been written in `if(!IsPostback)` condition. Either remove the if condition or assign value from the dropdown's selected index changed event as shown below.

**DropDown List :**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="PatientID" 
    DataValueField="PatientID" AutoPostback="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
```

**Code Behind :**

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   HospNo.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to `ToString()` a `string`, it is already a `string`.

Try checking to see if the drop down list's `SelectedItem` and `Text` actually are something before trying to set the text box's text value on every post back, like this:

```
// Check to see if the selected item of the drop down list is something or not
if(DropDownList1.SelectedItem != null)
{
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text)
    {
        HospNo.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
}

//other code
```

Note: This logic will check to see if a selected item exists on each post back to the server and only show the text value when there is a selected item in the drop down list.

Comment: @SatwikMn - see updated answer to check if `SelectedItem` of the drop down list is not `null`.

Comment: its not showing any exception now but the selected item ins not being displaye in the textbox

Comment: @SatwikMn - remove the outer `if` condition, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DropDownList1.AutoPostBack= true;
        string pid = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        HospNo.Text = pid.ToString();//Error in this line

        //other code
     }
 }
```

Comment: Rather than just posting code, please consider adding an explanation on what is the problem with code in question and how your code would solve it. That would make it more useful for future readers. Just a suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning values on page load where drop down selection is not yet made.

You should give values to drop down and code can be as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        HospNo.Text = DropDownList1.Text;

    //other code
    }
 }
```

If you have default selected value then you can do it through:

```
HospNo.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
```

But in your case it seems null, thats why the error is there

Answer (score 0):

You should put this code inside the dropdown change event.

Register the change event

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnChange="DropDownList1_Change"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="PatientID" 
    DataValueField="PatientID">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Code behind

```
protected void DropDownList1_Change(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        string pid = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        HospNo.Text = pid.ToString();//Error in this line

}
```

This can be easily done in client side using Jquery/Javascript as well.